# How to sort point cloud in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the text file of point cloud data, for example

```
[17.42851 7.370431 -0.8465996                                            
17.3368 7.309645 -0.6999135
17.17311 7.201123 -0.4422026 
17.26928 7.269999 -0.5591076 
17.09828 7.153707 -0.3068624 
17.59379 7.476501 -0.8979237]
```

In above .txt file in first row first value indicates x coordinate, 2nd indicates y and 3rd indicates z coordinate.
By using `uiimport` command in matlab , I imported it but the problem is, I want to plot these points layer by layer, so how should I separate it layer by layer? Please tell me the command from matlab.

Comment: What do you mean by 'layer by layer'?

Comment: it means for every z coordinate we have to plot x and y coordinate in that plane and then go for next z coordinate(or next plane)

Comment: so you want a 2d plot for every z value in the data? in the example data you provided every point seems to have a different z value, so you'll get a plot for every point containing only one point. maybe you want to specify a range for each layer?

Answer (score 2):

your matrix:

```
A = [17.42851 7.370431 -0.8465996;                                            
17.3368 7.309645 -0.6999135;
17.17311 7.201123 -0.4422026; 
17.26928 7.269999 -0.5591076; 
17.09828 7.153707 -0.3068624; 
17.59379 7.476501 -0.8979237];
```

has the length:

```
L = size(A,1);
```

First you need to replicate it:

```
B = repmat(A,L,1);
```

and then sort the last row (z):

```
B(:,3) = sort(B(:,3))
```

which results in:

```
   17.4285    7.3704   -0.8979
   17.3368    7.3096   -0.8979
   17.1731    7.2011   -0.8979
   17.2693    7.2700   -0.8979
   17.0983    7.1537   -0.8979
   17.5938    7.4765   -0.8979
   ...
   17.4285    7.3704   -0.3069
   17.3368    7.3096   -0.3069
   17.1731    7.2011   -0.3069
   17.2693    7.2700   -0.3069
   17.0983    7.1537   -0.3069
   17.5938    7.4765   -0.3069
```

which you then could plot with

```
scatter3(B(:,1),B(:,2),B(:,3));
```

leading to:
[image: scatter plot]

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you want to plot each plane.

```
scatter(x,y,2,z)
```

will plot a 2D plot of x and y coordinates with points of size 2. The colours of the plot will be the linear mapping of the z coordinates.

You can proceed in the same fashion for the other planes...

```
scatter(x,z,2,y)
```

will plot the xz plane

Alternatively you could just plot the 3D pointcloud using

```
scatter3(x,y,z)
```

then click on the rotate button in the MATLAB figure and right click on the figure to change the view (to xy, xz,yz plane)